# WooCommerce conditional required checkout fields

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to change the required billing fields based on a custom filed that I've added:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields' );

function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields)
{
    $fields['my_options'] = array(
        'label' => __('Order as'),
        'required' => true,
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'person' => __('Person')            
            'company' => __('Company'),
            ),
        'priority' => 0
    );   

    $fields['billing_options'] = array(
        'label' => __('Tax Number'), 
        'required' => true, 
        'clear' => false, 
        'type' => 'text',
        'priority' => 31
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

So if the user selects 'Person' in the drop down option I would like the:

- company name,
- 'billing_options'

fileds to be no longer required.

And when 'Company' is selected the:

- List item

Name and Surname 
are not required but:

- company name,
- 'billing_options'

are required.

So far I've been trying to use the `woocommerce_checkout_process` hook but without any luck. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Personally, I find this WooCommerce is off-topic stance ridiculous. Anyway, since I cannot answer, I comment my solution. Use the `woocommerce_checkout_posted_data` filter to examine the data and initially have all fields as required. Examine the data, and simply conditionally remove with `unset($data['field_you_want_to_ignore'])`. Since the field is then missing from the data sent for validation, it does not fail, yet still validates those fields you keep in the posted `$data`.